# Homomorphism of adic rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Consider an adic ring, i.e. a topological ring $R$ equipped with $I$-adic topology (fundamental open neighborhoods of $0$ given by $I^n$) for an ideal $I$ such that moreover $R\cong \lim_n R/I^n$.

1. I want to say that continuous homomorphism of adic rings $f\colon(R,I)\to (S,I)$ is the same as a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$ such that $f(I)\subseteq J$. Is that true?
2. If not: for an adic ring $(R,I)$, consider the ideal $I_{tnil}$ of topologically nilpotent elements w.r.t. $I$-adic topology. Can we at least say that giving a continuous homomorphism $f\colon(R,I)\to (S,I)$ is the same as giving a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$ such that $f(I_{tnil})\subseteq J_{tnil}$?

Comment: See EGA I, preliminaries on topological rings: https://fppf.site/ega/ega0-auto.pdf (see section 7).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is $f(I^m) \subset J$ for some $m$.

If there is such a $m$ then $f$ is obviously continuous. No need that $m=1$ as the identity $R=k[[t]],I=(t)\to S=k[[t]],J=(t^2)$ is obviously continuous.

If there is no such $m$ then there is a sequence $a_k\in I^k$ such that $f(a_k)\not\in J$ so that $a_k\to 0$ in $R$ but $f(a_k) \not\to 0$ in $S$, whence $f$ is not continuous.

It is not obvious to me if the condition $f(I_{tnil})\subseteq J_{tnil}$ is sufficient.